# Pass rufus-scheduler logs to production.log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, rufus-scheduler

How can I redirect all logs from [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) to log/production.log?

For example, in console I can see something like that:

```
↳ config/initializers/XXX_scheduler.rb:15
{ 70173962355140 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  70173962355140   job:
  70173962355140     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "43 12 * * *" {}
  70173962355140   error:
  70173962355140     70173962355140
  70173962355140     NoMethodError
  70173962355140     undefined method passenger_user for nil:NilClass
...
```

I found this error text in puma error (puma.error.log) file on production. 
Part of deploy.rb:

`set :puma_error_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"`

How can I redirect all logs related to rufus-scheduler to production.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.

What you are seeing is the output of `Scheduler#on_error`. By default it outputs to stderr.

This destination can be overriden as [explained in the readme](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufusschedulerstderr) but it's probably better to override `#on_error`, as [detailed in the readme](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufusscheduleron_errorjob-error) as well.

Your `#on_error` might thus look like

```rb
def scheduler.on_error(job, error)

  Rails.logger.error(
    "err#{error.object_id} rufus-scheduler intercepted #{error.inspect}" +
    " in job #{job.inspect}")
  error.backtrace.each_with_index do |line, i|
    Rails.logger.error(
      "err#{error.object_id} #{i}: #{line}")
  end
end
```

and thus simply piggyback Rails logging infrastructure.

The [original #on_error](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/a501a16c450da0813bc4ce719c87a42eaeed6e3d/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb#L440-L499) is quite detailed. Feel free to take inspiration from it if you need more debugging information.